# Dijkstra running slow

Tags: algorithm, performance, graph, dijkstra

There is a problem at Spoj called HIGHWAYS, that is basically to find the shortest path between 2 given cities.

The first time I solved it, I used Dijkstra algorithm... I got it right, although the code was kind of big, so I decided to redo it with smaller code (that obviously acts the same way), but it's getting Time Limit Exceeded.

I'd like to know what difference between them is making this TLE to happen.

The input is like this:

```
n            //number of test cases
c e s e      //number of cities (from 1 to c), number of edges, start and end cities
c1 c2 w      //e lines, each with connection between c1 and c2 with weight w
```

Here are the long code (Accepted):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define si(n) scanf("%d", &n)
#define INF 99999
int d[100010];

struct edge {
        int v, weight;

        edge(int a, int w) {
                v = a;
                weight = w;
        }

        bool operator < (const edge & o) const {
                return weight > o.weight;
        }

};

struct vertex {
        int value;
        vector <edge> adj;

        vertex() {
            adj.clear();
        }

        vertex(int val) {
                value = val;
                adj.clear();
        }

        void add(edge a) {
                adj.push_back(a);
        }
};

struct graph {
        vertex v[100010];

        void add_v(int val) {
                vertex a(val);
                a.adj.clear();
                v[val] = a;
        }
        void add_a(int v1, int v2, int p) {
                v[v1].add(edge(v2, p));
                v[v2].add(edge(v1, p));
        }

        void dijkstra(int n, int f) {
                for(int i = 0; i <= f; i++ ) d[i] = INF;
                priority_queue < edge > Q;
                d[n] = 0;
                int current;


                Q.push(edge(n, 0));

                while (!Q.empty()) {

                    current = Q.top().v;
                    Q.pop();
                    for (int i = 0; i < v[current].adj.size(); i++) {
                        edge a = v[current].adj[i];
                        if (d[a.v] > d[current] + a.weight) {
                            d[a.v] = d[current] + a.weight;
                            Q.push(edge(a.v, d[a.v]));
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
};

int main(){

    int cases;
    si(cases);

    int v, a, ini, fim;
    int v1, v2, w;
    while(cases--){
        si(v); si(a);
        si(ini); si(fim);

        graph g;

        for(int i = 1; i <= v; i++){
            g.add_v(i);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
            si(v1); si(v2); si(w);
            g.add_a(v1, v2, w);
        }

        g.dijkstra(ini, v+1);
        int dist = d[fim];

        if(dist < 0 || dist >= INF) printf("NONE\n");
        else printf("%d\n", dist);

    }

}
```

Here is the short one (Time Limit Exceeded):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct edge{
    int v, w;
    edge(){}
    edge(int a, int b){v = a; w = b;}
};
bool operator < (edge a, edge b) {return a.w < b.w;}
const int INF = INT_MAX;
typedef vector<vector<edge> > graph;
typedef priority_queue<edge> heap;
int d[100020];

void Dijkstra(graph G, int length, int s){
    for(int i = 1; i <= length; i++) d[i] = INF;
    edge base;
    base.v = s;
    base.w = d[s] = 0;
    heap H;
    H.push(base);

    while(!H.empty()){
        int current = H.top().v;
        H.pop();
        for (int i = 0; i < G[current].size(); i++) {
            edge a = G[current][i];
            if (d[a.v] > d[current] + a.w) {
                d[a.v] = d[current] + a.w;
                H.push(edge (a.v, d[a.v]));
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int cases;
    int n, m, s, e;
    int v1, v2, w;

    scanf("%d", &cases);
    while(cases--){
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &n, &m, &s, &e);
        graph G(n + 1);

        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
            scanf("%d %d %d", &v1, &v2, &w);
            G[v1].push_back(edge(v2, w));
            G[v2].push_back(edge(v1, w));
        }

        Dijkstra(G, n, s);

        if(d[e] != INF) printf("%d\n", d[e]);
        else printf("NONE\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in how you control the priority queue. In the long version, you take the edges with a small weight first, which enables you to find the optimum earlier and cut many possible paths short:

```
    bool operator < (const edge & o) const {
            return weight > o.weight;
    }
```

In the short version, you have the behaviour (accidentially?) reversed and always take the edge with the greatest weight, which means that you effectively probe all possible paths.

```
    bool operator < (edge a, edge b) {return a.w < b.w;}
```

Change the inequality operator and both versions will run equally fast.

Comment: I just forgot heaps in c++ are maxheaps, so I missed the comparation side.. it worked now, thanks !

Answer (score -1):

The containers of STL are slow. Avoid using vector if necessary.

here is my dij:

```
class graph
{
public :
    int head[N],next[M],node[M];
    int dist[M];
    int tot;
    void init()
    {
        tot = 0;
        CLR(head,-1);
    }
    void add(int x,int y,int z = 1)
    {
        node[tot] = y;
        dist[tot] = z;
        next[tot] = head[x];
        head[x] = tot++;
    }
    graph() {init();}
} g;
int dist[N]; ///the distance
///src means source. ter is optional, it means terminal
void dij(int src, graph &g, int ter=-1) 
{
    memset(dist,0x3f,sizeof(dist)); ///init d[i] as a very large value
    dist[src] = 0;
    priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<pair<int,int> >,greater<pair<int,int> > > pq;
    pq.push(make_pair(dist[src],src));
    while(!pq.empty())
    {
        int x = pq.top().second;
        int d = pq.top().first;
        if(d != dist[x])continue;
        if(x == ter)return ;
        for(int i = g.head[x] ; ~i ; i = g.next[i])
        {
            int y = g.node[i];
            if(d+g.dist[i]<dist[y])
            {
                dist[y] = d + g.dist[i];
                pq.push(make_pair(dist[y],y));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "The containers of STL are slow" Err, no. The STL container classes are heavily optimised for speed, I would think. Anyway, inefficient containers don't explain the huge performace difference between the two posted versions.